# Use Ignite cluster groups into Vert.x

Tags: cluster-computing, vert.x, ignite

I have a question about Ignite cluster manager with Vert.x. With Ignite it's possible to define cluster groups to "select" nodes we want to work with. So it could be possible to create distinct areas to deploy different kind of verticle with Vert.X.

Is it on the roadmap to use this feature in next versions of Vert.x? It would be nice to provide attributes or predicates (CPU / RAM for example) for verticle deployment (to restrict the Verticle deployment scope).

Am I missing something obvious which could let me do it? Does anyone tried to achieve this (choosing the scope of Verticle deployment in term of machines/Ignite instances)?

Thank you for your interest on my question.

Best regards

Comment: I believe that better place to the question is one of the community channel from this page: http://vertx.io/community/

At present `ClusterManager` interface doesn't declare any of mentioned capabilities. Also I think that this capabilities are hardly implementable because under the hood of `ClusterManager` implementation could be anything that can keep data in distributed manner (e.g. JGroups or ZooKeeper) but don't have any features related with resource management at all.

Comment: You are right it's not the well apropriate place for this question, sorry. Thank you to take the time to answer me :)